# threejs, how to remove objects from octree?

Tags: three.js

In this example: https://threejs.org/examples/games_fps.html

This line adds an object to the octree: `worldOctree.fromGraphNode( gltf.scene );`

Let's say I spawn a player body, it gets fragged and I want to remove that object from the worldOctree, so that it doesn't participate in collisions anymore. How do I remove an object from the octree?

Comment: You can see all the available methods on Octree [by looking at its source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/math/Octree.js).

Comment: @Marquizzo that doesn't answer my question. Do you see a method there to remove objects from the octree? What is the name of the method, what is the line number?

Comment: Alternatively, if this is not implemented in threejs's octree, if someone has experience with another scene graph where this is implemented, please point it out. If there is a specific tutorial or general architecture for such removal in threejs, I'd appreciate it and find it useful.